# Progress Bar in Applescript window

Tags: bash, macos, shell, applescript, osascript

I want to download different apps with a bash script on macOS.

As there are some larger downloads (e.g. Office 365) I would like to include a progress bar in a regular macOS Window.

The applications download+install script looks like this

```
cd ~/Downloads/ && { curl -O https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg ; cd -; }
sudo hdiutil attach ~/Downloads/googlechrome.dmg
sudo cp -r /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications/
diskutil unmount Google\ Chrome
```

But this does not show any progress for the user (script will run in background).

I found the following example and edited it a bit to my likings

```
chromedl() {
    osascript <<AppleScript
    set progress description to "Loading"
set progress additional description to "Please wait"
set progress total steps to 3
repeat with i from 1 to 4
   set theSourceCode to do shell script "curl -L -m 30 seconds [url=https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg]https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg]"
   set progress completed steps to i
end repeat
display dialog "Progress bar is complete."
AppleScript
```

But this creates a curl execution error.

Please help me with a functioning Curl Download + Progress Bar script

Comment: AppleScript doesn't know the progress of shell scripts - how are you getting values from the download, such as total and current sizes, to use with the progress indicator?  Or are you just looking for an indeterminate indicator (spinner)?

Comment: @red_menace a progress bar would be ideal, but a spinner would also be a solution. I just want the user to have some visual feedback that the script is working.

Answer (score 0):

A basic progress spinner window is easy enough to create using AppleScriptObjectiveC. Copy the following into Script Editor and run it in the foreground (command-control-R, or use the menu command Script→Run in Foreground, which appears when you hold down the control key).

```
use framework "AppKit"
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite 10.10 or later required
use scripting additions

-- convenience properties to make ASOC more readable
property ca : current application
property NSPanel : class "NSPanel"
property NSView : class "NSView"
property NSProgressIndicator : class "NSProgressIndicator"
property NSTextField : class "NSTextField"

property HUD_mask : 8192
property nonactivating_mask : 128

global progress_panel, progress_indicator, label_field

make_progress_panel()
progress_indicator's startAnimation:me
progress_panel's orderFront:me

-- just hang it out there for 5 seconds as proof of concept
delay 5

progress_panel's |close|()

on make_progress_panel()
    -- make floating panel
    set content_rect to ca's NSMakeRect(200, 800, 140, 80)
    set progress_panel to NSPanel's alloc's initWithContentRect:content_rect styleMask:(HUD_mask + nonactivating_mask) backing:(ca's NSBackingStoreBuffered) defer:true
    set progress_panel's floatingPanel to true

    -- make progress indicator
    set progress_rect to ca's NSMakeRect(0, 0, 40, 40)
    set progress_indicator to NSProgressIndicator's alloc's initWithFrame:progress_rect
    set progress_indicator's indeterminate to true
    set progress_indicator's |style| to 1
    set progress_indicator's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

    --make text field
    set label_field to NSTextField's labelWithString:"Downloading"
    set label_field's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

    -- make container view, and add subviews
    set content_view to NSView's alloc's initWithFrame:content_rect
    content_view's addSubview:label_field
    content_view's addSubview:progress_indicator
    progress_indicator's sizeToFit()

    set progress_panel's contentView to content_view

    -- view constraints, for alignment
    set pi_y_centering to progress_indicator's centerYAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(content_view's centerYAnchor)
    set lf_y_centering to label_field's centerYAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(content_view's centerYAnchor)
    pi_y_centering's setActive:true
    lf_y_centering's setActive:true

    set lf_left_margin to content_view's leadingAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(label_field's leadingAnchor) |constant|:-10
    lf_left_margin's setActive:true

    set pi_left_margin to label_field's trailingAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(progress_indicator's leadingAnchor) |constant|:-10
    pi_left_margin's setActive:true

    set pi_right_margin to progress_indicator's trailingAnchor's constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:(content_view's trailingAnchor) |constant|:10
    pi_left_margin's setActive:true
end make_progress_panel
```

The simplest way to make this work with `curl`, I think, is to detach the curl process entirely and recover its pid, like so (the code at the end detaches the process and sends the output to oblivion, then returns the pid):

```
set curl_pid to do shell script "curl -L [url=...] &> /dev/null & echo $!"
```

Once you have the pid you can set up a loop (or an idle handler, if you create an app) and periodically check to see if the process is still active:

```
try
    set b to do shell script "pgrep curl | grep " & curl_pid
on error
    progress_indicator's stopAnimation:me
    progress_panel's |close|()
end try
```

If you want a determinate progress bar, that's easy enough to manage, but you have to figure out a way to measure progress. [This link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450402/how-to-retrieve-downloadable-file-size-with-curl-command) suggests you can get the headers for a file first and extract the file size; you could compare that against the actual on-disk file size as the download progresses, and feed the ratio into the progress bar.